# How to remove Preference underlining

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am developing some app and I need to remove lines between Preferences, as shown on screenshot. Could you please help me to do that?
NOTE: I'm not going to change System Setting. This is just an example. The idea is to remove lines between Preferences in PreferenceActivity.
[image]

Comment: Post some relevant code and I'm sure people will help ...

Comment: @Mark I wish to post something, which at least tries to remove those lines, but I could not find the solution. Posting a standard code for PreferenceActivity (and its layout) is not useful in this case, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The line you want to hide is called 'divider'. `PreferenceActivity` extends `ListActivity` and as you may expect it uses `ListView`. You can change a divider in a `ListView`. In your `PreferenceActivity`:

```
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        lv.setDividerHeight(0);
```

Check other topics [android preference horizontal divider in custom preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481896/android-preference-horizontal-divider-in-custom-preference), [how to hide the divider between preferences in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518115/how-to-hide-the-divider-between-preferences-in-fragment), [Change Divider color in Android PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667367/change-divider-color-in-android-preferenceactivity)